# How does Ruby handle variable assignment in dead code?

Tags: ruby

The following snippet

```
if false
  p 'should not happen'
  foo = 42
end

p defined? foo
p foo.inspect
```

When evaluated it prints out `"local-variable"` and `"nil"`. Please explain what Ruby is doing behind the scenes.